# Filtering rows saving result in a new column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset as follows

```
Name    Surname    Username   Tweet                      Tags    
Matthew Fields     m.fields  I love summertime            summer summertime sun holiday
Fion    Stewart     fion     It is time to enjoy ourselves time
Christine Bold     chris89   Enjoy your summer            summer
Vera    Lovable    v.lov2    It's sunny outside           sun summer holiday
```

I would like to search the following list of strings within three columns (Username, Tweet and Tags):

```
list_strings=['summer','summertime','sun','holiday']
```

to see if at least in one column there is one or more of the terms above. This check should be saved in a new column, Terms from list, where there will be stored the terms found in all the columns (with no duplicates, i.e. if the same term is present in more column, I would need only to mention once).

The expected output would be:

```
Name    Surname    Username   Tweet                      Tags                              Terms from list
Matthew Fields     m.fields  I love summertime            summer summertime sun holiday    summer, summertime, sun, holiday
Christine Bold     chris89   Enjoy your summer            summer                            summer
Vera    Lovable    v.lov2    It's sunny outside           sun summer holiday               sun, summer, holiday
```

Could you please give me any advice on how to do this and point me in the right direction? thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `str.contains`

```
df=df[df['Tweet'].str.contains('|'.join(list_strings))]
```

If multiple columns

```
df=df[df[['Tweet','Tags']].apply(lambda x : x.str.contains('|'.join(list_strings))).any(1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the steps below.

step 1: for each element in df if any word in the string (x.split(' ')[i] == string) is also a word in list_strings keep it else it will give an empty list ([]). i.e. we will have a list of lists (of length 1 or zero). So we choose the first item from the list (val[0]) if it exists.

```
list_strings=['summer','summertime','sun','holiday']

step1 = df[['Username', 'Tweet', 'Tags']].applymap(lambda x: (([val[0] for val in [([string  for i in range(len(x.split(' '))) if (x.split(' ')[i] == string )]) for string in list_strings ] if val]) ))
```

step 2: we assign to the column "Terms in List" the unique elements of the combined lists from the three columns.

```
df['Terms in list'] = step1.apply(lambda x: set(x[0]  + x[1]  + x[2]), axis = 1)
```